# How to select class with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this `ng-repeat`:

**HTML:**

```
<td class="border" data-ng-repeat="price in goHead.prices track by $index">
```

In my `<td>` `data-ng-if="price.isMinPrice"` choose `class="border` `else data-ng-if="! price.isMinPrice"` choose `class="noBorder"`.

Is it possible to do this in AngularJS?

Comment: This is exactly what ng-class is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible ( you can use `ng-class` ):

```
<td ng-repeat="price in goHead.prices track by $index" ng-class="{border: price.isMinPrice, noBorder: !price.isMinPrice}">
</td>
```

Or you can write:

```
<td ng-repeat="price in goHead.prices track by $index" class="{{price.isMinPrice ? 'border' : 'noBorder'}}">
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AngularJs [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

```
<td 
 data-ng-repeat="price in goHead.prices track by $index"
 data-ng-class="{border: price.isMinPrice, noBorder: !price.isMinPrice}">
...
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<td class="border"
    data-ng-repeat="price in goHead.prices track by $index"
    ng-class="{border: price.isMinPrice, noBorder: !price.isMinPrice}"
    >
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ngClass directive provided by angularjs.
The `ngClass` directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.
Example:

```
...
<p ng-class="{strike: deleted, bold: important}">Map Syntax Example</p>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="deleted"> deleted (apply "strike" class)<br>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="important"> important (apply "bold" class)<br>
...
```

Try this, will help you.